# Photosmart 7520 set up

Tags: wireless, printing

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  I am trying to set up a photosmart 7520 wireless.  I have the drivers that's supposed to work. 3.12.9, but the error message says it can't find the printer.  The printer's config. print out lists my computer as a MAC.
I am really, really new at this and I haven't ever done anything more involved than use the computer.  Any help there for me?

Answer (score 0):

The HP print drivers are installed in Ubuntu by default - access to them from a terminal is very easy and quick.

First, open a terminal windows (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

Enter the command `hp-setup`

This will open the HP Device Manager.  If your printer is connected via USB, choose the first option.  For a wireless printer you can choose either the second or third options.  I generally use the second option.

[image: HP Device Manager Screenshot]

From here, choose 'next' and your printer will appear in a list of possible printers.  You should choose your printer from the list, even if it is the only printer in the list.  Then press 'next' twice.

Your printer is setup and ready to go.

Should you also want a nice little indicator icon in the toolbar, use the command

`sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`

which will install the HP Toolbox to assist you in monitoring your printer, and it's ink levels.

Comment: I'm not using the USB.  When I use the 2nd option, and hit next, I get "no devices found"  If I use option 3, will I still be able to go wireless?                             @charles Green

Comment: yes, but 1st check that your printer is connecting to your network

Comment: After it says my printer is configured and unplug the usb, if I  unplug it and hit finish, it takes me back to the first screen.  If I don't hit finish, it doesn't print unless I plug in the usb.

Comment: I believe that after you finish, you need to repeat the process using the second option.

Comment: Just tried that.  It is still the same.

Comment: I note from some other threads on different websites, that there are other people having issues like this with the HP 7520 as well.

Comment: I now have the tool box and icon.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Click on: Show Advanced Options. Try it with other network discovery method.